# How to install OwlCarousel in Laravel 7?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, owl-carousel

How can I install OwlCarousel in Laravel 7? I tried using cdnjs.

Within the HTML I have the code below:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('inc.navbar')
        <div class="container">
            @include('inc.messages')
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

And in my index.blade.php I have this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
            <div> Your Content</div>
            <div> Your Content</div>
            <div> Your Content</div>
            <div> Your Content</div>
            <div> Your Content</div>
            <div> Your Content</div>
            <div> Your Content</div>
        </div>
```

When I load the page I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

How can I install the OwlCarousel in Laravel project?